# Tricky path integral with arccos

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, parametric

For my homework I have to take the path integral of $F=<\arccos x,xy-e^y>$ over the triangular path from $(0,0)$ to $(2,3)$ to $(2,0)$ and back to $(0,0)$. I have broken this integral into three separate integrals, and my first integral looks like this:

$$ \int  <\arccos(2t), 6t^2-e^{3t}>• <2,3>dt$$

However this is leading to some crazy results with imaginary numbers... am i setting this up wrong?

Comment: Your notation is completely meaningless to me

Comment: I assume you meant this question to be the same as the one you asked on StackOverflow, but you left out the definition of function $F$. I have edited it in--change it if you meant something else. Note that your notation for the integral is non-standard. Did you mean the dot product (you wrote the cross product)? Where is the $dt$ symbol? Are the angle brackets in your definition of $F$ and your square brackets in the integral both meant to show points? What are the limits on the integral?

Comment: Yes sorry, i am not used to typing equations into stack overflow. I fixed it, it is supposed to be the dot product of F(c(t)) and c’(t) intgrated from 1 to 0.

Comment: Try Green’s theorem.

Comment: It's not a question of setting it up wrong; the value of $\arccos x$ is complex at $x=2$, so it's not surprising that you get complex numbers.

Comment: I’m just confused why an integral would give complex numbers.... is this a joke from my teacher? Lol (trying greens theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What is the value of the integral of $g(x) dx$ over a closed path in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: 0?        I’m not sure how to use greens theorem on a parametrized equation. I’m so confused haha.